# SQL connecting 3 seperate tables using procedures

Tags: sql, database, procedure

I'm struggling with SQL a bit, so far I have 3 tables:

CUSTOMER

id,
name,
surname,
gender,
birthdate

GENDER

id,
gender

ADRESS

id,
country,
city

I need to create a procedure on connecting these 3 tables into a big one, so it would have (customer id, name, gender, country)

I know that I have to use joins but I am so unfamiliar with SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You should just use a `JOIN` we use a `JOIN` on 2 or more tables in order to fetch some common attributes related values of one table that exists in other as together. So, here the sql then would look like. Also you dont require the gender seperate table as you have gender already present in your customer table

```
   Select 
   c.id, c.name, c.gender, a.country
   From CUSTOMER c 
   Join
   Address a
   On c.id =a.id
```